# Changing android dynamic image size programmatically

Tags: android, dynamic, imageview, size

I'm trying to resize a dynamic image in android but I can't, maybe someone can help me. I have searched in the web but didn't find anything useful...

This is the code I'm using to create and place the image:

```
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setOnClickListener(this);

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageBitmap(getImage());

        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(10, 10);
        iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
        row.addView(iv);
```

Comment: what do you mean by resize a dynamic image? What's your goal?

Comment: resize = change the size of the image. If it's 400x400 px change it to 10x10 for example

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, based on your snippet:

```
    //...
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    iv.setImageBitmap(getImage());

    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(10, 10);
    row.addView(iv, lp);
```